# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object and works on server but not on PC

Tags: python, regex, linux, server

### Introduction

I have problem with python program written in python 3.4.2. At the beginning i want to say, that it's not my program. 
When i connect with server by SSH and compile it, it works just fine.

### Server and PC specification

:[image]

...and from my PC:
[image]

I have different Python version, but i can't compile it at 3.4.2, because there is no typing module for this specific version, which i need. I don't know if **GCC version** could cause this problem, but i've tried different versions. 
I've downloaded it, and tried to compile it by myself. I run it in the exactly same way.

### The real problem

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gads.py", line 28, in <module>
    lists = list_working.ListWorking(files_data)
  File "/home/grzesiek/googleads/lib/list_working.py", line 43, in __init__
    self._acc = self._split_str_list(list_data['accepted']['content'])
  File "/home/grzesiek/googleads/lib/common.py", line 69, in _split_str_list
    splited = re.split(separator, content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/re.py", line 203, in split
    return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

So far i know that **ListWorking(files_data)** passes some files which are dictionaries, and at the end when i want to use **regex** it throws an error. But i can't change these dictionaries to strings or lists, because then it compiles, but erase data that i provide to **ListWorking()**
Here is fragment of code which i've tried to change:

```
 def __init__(self, list_data: dict) -> None:
        self._acc = self._split_str_list(list_data['accepted']['content'])
        self._acc = self._del_dup(self._acc)
        self._ign = self._split_str_list(list_data['ignored']['content'])
        self._ign = self._del_dup(self._ign)
        self._pro = self._split_str_list(list_data['protected']['content'])
        self._pro = self._del_dup(self._pro)
        self._fign = self._split_str_list(list_data['full_ignored']['content'])
        self._fign = self._del_dup(self._fign)
        self._key = self._split_str_list(list_data['keywords']['content'])
        self._key = self._del_dup(self._key)
        self._unk = self._split_str_list(list_data['unknown']['content'])
        self._unk = self._del_dup(self._unk)
        self._sw = self._split_str_list(list_data['stopwords']['content'])
```

And where the last error occurs:

```
def _split_str_list(content: str, separator: str = '\n') -> list:
    """Split string to list"""
    splited = re.split(separator, content)
    splited = list(x.strip() for x in splited)
    splited = list(filter(None, splited))
    return splited
```

Also, in Python 3.4.2 it comes to `import typing` and throws an error, because there is no typing lib in this version of Python. 
*So - how is it possible to work fine on Linux server but it doesn't on my PC?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer was much simpler than i thought it would be...
I just had to install correct version of **enca**, code author didn't wrote the specific informations if something is missing, so it was very hard to find, because whole project has about ~5000 lines of code, and enca was used only by one function.
*It had nothing to do with Linux or GCC.*